# Google Script: How to automatically add the attachment from Google drive based on the email subject?

Tags: email, google-sheets, attachment

I need the script to automatically attach the file to the email. The files are located in the Google drive. The name of the files are the same as the email subjects. 1 PDF per subject. Please help!

Part of the code is this:

```
  function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 1000);

  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = objects[i];


    var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
    if (rowData.emailAddress1 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress1, rowData.subject, emailText);
    }
     if (rowData.emailAddress2 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress2, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress3 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress3, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress4 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress4, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress5 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress5, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress6 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress6, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress7 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress7, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress8 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress8, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress9 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress9, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
    if (rowData.emailAddress10 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress10, rowData.subject, emailText);
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the file in Drive based on the subject and add it as an attachment.

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(rowData.subject);

if (files.hasNext()) {

  MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress1, rowData.subject, emailText, {
      attachments: [files.next().getBlob()]
  });

}
```

Comment: this also works for me: var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData); 
    var id = DriveApp.getFileById(rowData.attachment);
    if (rowData.emailAddress1 != null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress1, rowData.subject, emailText, {attachments:[id]});
    }